# Let me go. How to change this sentence into passive voice?

Tags: sentence-construction, active-voice

Let me go. 
How to change this sentence into passive voice? Are they correct?

> I am allowed to go.
>  
>   I should be allowed to go.
>   I may be allowed to go.

Please define it with solid reasons

Comment: Why do you want to change that sentence into passive?  Is it one of those school exercises that have no connection with what people say?

Comment: Why can't I see your comments here?

Comment: The imperative can't be passivized.  You can paraphrase it, but those aren't passive versions of the original imperative, they're just sentences with similar meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of your three examples, "I should be allowed to go" is the best. However, "I should be let go" would be more faithful to the original.

One situation when we sometimes need to change imperative verbs to passives is when we are reporting what someone else has said. This is called "reported speech".

For example, if Jack has said, "Let me go", you might later tell someone:

- "Jack told the police TO LET HIM GO." This is the normal way to change an imperative to reported speech: imperative ==> infinitive with "to".
- Or you could say, "Jack told the police (that) THEY SHOULD LET HIM GO."
- Or (in the passive, like your example), "Jack told the police (that) HE SHOULD BE LET GO."

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can change a command into the passive, but here's a try:

(That) I am let go by you!

Define it? The active verb (let me go) is put in the passive, an agent (by you) is added, and the "that" heads a wish or imperative clause,as in

(I demand/wish) (that) I am let go by you!